# How to use C# 8.0 with Godot 3.3.2?

Tags: c#, godot

I am trying to use the `System.Range` and `System.Index` classes with new C# v8.0 construct, see ([here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range?view=net-5.0)). But, I cannot make it work. I have tried under Windows with .NET 5.0 and under Ubuntu with Mono 6 but I got the same result:

First I have changed the `.csproj` file like that:

```
<Project Sdk="Godot.NET.Sdk/3.3.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Note the `<LangVersion>` set at 8.0. With that parameter, I can now build the project with this kind of snippet:

```
int[] nb = {1, 2, 3};
GD.Print(nb[1..2]);
```

But at runtime, I got this error:
`Predefined type 'System.Range' is not defined or imported`

---

EDIT: To answer the comments.

I had to add `using System.Runtime` to make the project able to build.

I had tried to change target framework to `.net5.0` (that was only possible on Windows). The project was still able to build but the error at runtime was different:

```
E 0:00:01.563   debug_send_unhandled_exception_error: System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000010 from typeref (expected class 'System.Range' in assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
  <C++ Error>   Unhandled exception
  <C++ Source>  modules/mono/mono_gd/gd_mono_utils.cpp:423 @ debug_send_unhandled_exception_error()
```

But this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163887/could-not-resolve-type-with-token-0100000f) made me think that the Mono assemblies used at runtime needs `net472`.

Another hint is that an important Godot project that claims to use C# v8.0, the beautiful Thrive, sets `net472` and `8.0` in their config file (see [here](https://github.com/Revolutionary-Games/Thrive/blob/master/Thrive.csproj))

Comment: Do you need some `using` directive to access that feature? Or is it really built into the core language? This site claims Godot can use C# 8.0: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_basics.html

Comment: I know little of custom .NET SDKs, but after looking at the source it appears the SDK is based on .NET Standard 2.0, while - according to Microsoft documentation - this requires .NET standard 2.1, .NET Core 3.0 or .NET 5.0 - Also Godot claims to support C# 8.0 and .NET 5.0 (according to Godot 3.3 release notes) - Thus, I'd say open an issue. Edit: wait, hold on, did you change target framework? You say you tried .NET 5.0 but your code snippet says net472.

Comment: I have edited the answer according to your remarks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was coming from TargetFramework!

If the option `.net5.0` is not supported by Godot, there is another option to have full System.Runtime feature of C# v8 `netstandard2.1`:

```
<Project Sdk="Godot.NET.Sdk/3.3.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The answer was given by a user called `31` on Github and Discord (see the closed issue [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/49439)).